# How to make a function for groupby based on number of inputs from user?

Tags: python, function, pandas

I have these two functions:

```
def groupByTwoParaCounter(dfName,grpByCol,paraCol1):
    print dfName[grpByCol].groupby([dfName[paraCol1],dfName[grpByCol]]).count()

def groupByThreeParaCounter(dfName,grpByCol,paraCol1,paraCol2):
    print dfName[grpByCol].groupby([dfName[paraCol1],dfName[paraCol2],dfName[grpByCol]]).count()
```

Here is some sample data:

```
Doc_ID  Batch_Num  Lot_Num Clinic_ID  Owner_ID Patient_Age
e14231  12345      NA      u2y5142    mys71262 29
```

I want to combine them into a single function. This is what I am looking for:

- I have a dataframe with several columns. I expect to do several groupby operations with varying number of input columns. What is a good way to write a single function for this purpose?

Comment: Could you provide some sample data?  What have you tried?  What is your expected result?

Comment: Thanks for the sample data.  What two examples with you expected result? I'm still not clear why you need a function for this vs. implementing it directly via `groupby`

Comment: You can pass a list of column names instead of columns to `groupby`, i.e., `df.groupby(['col1', 'col2'])` instead of `df.groupby([df['col1'], df['col2']])`. If you want to define a function for this simple task, you can pass a list (which can be variable length of course) as a grouping parameter.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you what you want:

```
def groupByCounter(dfName, grpByCol, *args):
    items = []
    for arg in args:
        items.append(dfName[arg])
    items.append(dfName[grpByCol])        
    print dfName[grpByCol].groupby(items).count()
```

It uses *, python's argument unpacking operator, which unpacks a variable number of arguments.

Comment: Doesn't work. This is the error: AssertionError: Grouper and axis must be same length

Comment: Added sample data. It's a standard dataframe. Nothing fancy